# How to share same data between multiple instances at inheritance levels?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I'd like to instance multiple object of the same inheritance levels, and for each of these level use the same data. So I think about inheritance and static members of a class.

This is my [attempt](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f40eb1e239be129f):

```
#include <iostream>

class Father
{
public:
    static int sValue;

    inline int GetValue() { return sValue * 10; }
};

class Child1 : public Father
{
public:
};

class Child2 : public Father
{
public:
};

int Father::sValue = 0;

int main()
{
    Child1 child1_1;
    Child1 child1_2;
    Child2 child2_1;
    Child2 child2_2;    


    child1_1.sValue = 1;
    child2_1.sValue = 2;    

    std::cout << child1_2.GetValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << child2_2.GetValue() << std::endl;
}
```

In my example both `Child1` instances should return 10 with `GetValue()`, and both `Child2` instances should return 20 using `GetValue()`. Since the function its the same, I don't want to override it for each child (that's why I placed it in `Father`).

The problem is that also `Child1` instances returns 20 calling `GetValue()`.

Thus `static` is shared across "main" parent, not child.

Since that `sValue` value is used into `GetValue()`, its correct to place it here. But I cannot separate static/same data so.

How would you do this?

Comment: Put the static member in each derived class?

Comment: @LogicStuff: nope, else I can't use `sValue` within the GetValue() (which is a common function) anymore...

Comment: Then make a `virtual` function `GetSValue` that will be used in `GetValue`.

Comment: Just have a constructor for child class and initialize Child objects' svalue when you create an instance of the object. Make sure svalue is not static.

Comment: @LogicStuff: but this means that I need to re-define GetSValue() (which is the same) for each child. Its redundant...

Comment: @macroland: nope, because once I edit one sValue, it should change for each instance. So `child1_1.sValue = 1;` should also change the value for `child1_2` automatically. (that's my target).

Comment: @paizza Other people comments above are right, while it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. If you explain the goal, then we can think about the proper way to realize it.

Comment: @peval27: its pretty explained: "In my example both Child1 instances should return 10 with GetValue(), and both Child2 instances should return 20 using GetValue(). Since the function its the same, I don't want to override it for each child (that's why I placed it in Father).
The problem is that also Child1 instances returns 20 calling GetValue()."

Comment: is it possible for you to use a non-static variable which is initialized by Child1 and Child2 constructor? if so, I'll write an answer.

Comment: @peval27: yes. But remember that once I change the value on one of Child1's instance, it must "propagate" to every Child1 instances.

Comment: @paizza so it won't work.

Comment: Of course! That's why I opened this topic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

splrs user has correctly identified your problem and the solution is correct. You need two different functions with two different static objects. You can avoid repeating the code, by using a template:

```
template<class Child>
struct Father {
    static int sValue;
    int GetValue() { /* ... */ }
};

struct Child1 : Father<Child1> {};
struct Child2 : Father<Child2> {};
```

This idiom is known as *Curiously recurring template pattern*.

---

Now of course, there is no common parent. If you need that, you can inherit the template from a non-template base:

```
struct FatherBase {};

template<class Child>
struct Father : FatherBase { /*...*/ };
```

And, if you need to access the different versions of `GetValue` from the base, then you need a virtual function:

```
struct FatherBase {
    virtual int GetValue() = 0;
};

template<class Child>
struct Father : FatherBase {
    // ...
    int GetValue() override { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with struct. I need class. A unique function for all child, and shared static for each derived level class. Can you give an example?

Comment: @paizza a struct is a class. I use it to keep the example concise. But use the class keyword if you like. Each child class has their own static member, inheritend from the templated father, yes. The examples are in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're modifying `Father::sValue` when you call `child1_1.sValue = 1;` and `child2_1.sValue = 2;` There's one instance, which belongs to `Father`, so however you access it (via a method against the classes or the instances) you'll get whatever it was set to prior to the call to `GetValue()`.

If you want a `Child1` and a `Child2` version then add static members and methods to those classes.

Comment: read my post. If I do so, `GetValue()` can't operate, and its a common function which must be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following can be what you're after:

```
class Father
{
public:
    inline int GetValue() { return DoGetValue() * 10; }
    void SetValue( int value ) { DoSetValue( value ); }

protected:
    virtual int DoGetValue() = 0;
    virtual void DoSetValue( int value ) = 0;
};


class Child1 : public Father
{
public:
    static int sValue;

protected:
    int DoGetValue() override { return sValue; }
    void DoSetValue( int value ) override { sValue = value; }
};

class Child2 : public Father
{
public:
    static int sValue;

protected:
    int DoGetValue() override { return sValue; }
    void DoSetValue( int value ) override { sValue = value; }
};

int Child1::sValue = 0;
int Child2::sValue = 0;

int main()
{
    Child1 child1_1;
    Child1 child1_2;
    Child2 child2_1;
    Child2 child2_2;    


    child1_1.SetValue( 1 );
    child2_1.SetValue( 2 );    

    std::cout << child1_2.GetValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << child2_2.GetValue() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is so redundant. If I have 20 variables instead of 1 (`sValue`), I need to re-declare it 20 times for each inheritance. The same for each getter/setter. I think I would try some `<functional>` operations.

Comment: @paizza maybe you want to do something that's not possible. Or at least I'm not aware of.

Comment: This is was I meant http://www.martin-finke.de/blog/articles/audio-plugins-016-polyphony/ . It says at some time: "Also, making the EnvelopeGenerator‘s stageValues static would mean that the volume and filter envelope are always the same. This could be solved through inheritance: We could make a VolumeEnvelope and FilterEnvelope class, and have both inherit from EnvelopeGenerator. stageValue could be static, and both VolumeEnvelopeand FilterEnvelope could override it". What does it means override static member?